# Find $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_{1,2,3}\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Consider $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x^3-x+a=0$ with $x_{1,2,3}\in\mathbb{C}$.
We need to find $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_{1,2,3}\in\mathbb{Z}$.
It seems be equivalent with to find **a** such that $f=x^3-x+a$ to be reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

$f=x^3-x+a=x(x^2-1)+a$, which involving that for $a=0$ it is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, and for any other value for $a\ne 0$ it seems be irreducible because we can't write $f$ like a product of two nonconstant lower degree polynomials , but I think it is not enough to prove that for $a=0$ is the only solution such that $x_{1,2,3}\in\mathbb{Z}$

---

> Exist another method to solve it ? We can use factorization over finite fields to prove that $a=0$ is the only solution ? Is enough to say that $f=x^3-x+a$ don't have integer roots because for $a\ne 0$, $f\ne g\cdot h$, because $x(x^2-1)$ is the unique factorization for $x^3-x$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The turning-points of the cubic $y=x^3-x$ are at $(\pm 1/\sqrt{3},\mp2/3\sqrt{3})$.  So, using the horizontal line test, if $b^3-b=c^3-c$ and $b,c\ne-1,0,1$, then $b=c$.  But then $(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)=(x-b)^3=x^3-3bx^2+3b^2x-b^3$, and the coefficient of $x^2$ shows that $b=0$.

Comment: Michael, you want to prove that $x^3-x$ is an injective function?

Comment: not between $y=2/3\sqrt{3}$ and $y-2/3\sqrt{3}$ because $0^3-0=1^3-1=(-1)^3-(-1)$.  But outside that range, yes it is.  The domain where it is not injective is between $\pm2/\sqrt{3}$.  The only integers in that domain are $0,1,-1$, and the only integer value of $y$ (or $a$) in there is $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find two integer values $x_1,x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then you have a point of intersection between the curve $y = x^3-x$ and a curve translated horizontally by the integer $x_2-x_1$.

The curves $y = x^3-x$ and $y = (x-n)^3-(x-n)$ have no intersection point for any integer $n$ when $|n| > 2$. The finite number of point of intersection you obtain with $|n| \le 2$ give you a finite number of possibilities to check for $a$.

Comment: mercio I can't understand this method, can you offer more details ?

Answer (score 1):

If one of the three integer roots $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ is $0$ then obviously $a=0$.

Suppose not. Relations between roots and coefficients of a polynomial give
\begin{equation*}
x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=0
\end{equation*}
and $x_{1}x_{2}+x_{2}x_{3}+x_{3}x_{1}=-1$ which rewrites as $x_{3}^{2}-x_{1}x_{2}=1=x_{2}x_{1}+x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}$. Using $x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}\geqslant |2x_{1}x_{2}|$ you see that this can only hold if $|x_{1}|=|x_{2}|=1$.

Similar considerations (with $x_{2},x_{3}$ instead of $x_{1},x_{2}$) give $|x_{1}|=|x_{2}|=|x_{3}|=1$  which is not possible when $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=0$.

I didn't find an arithmetic solution though. I know that writing $x(x^{2}-1)+a$ makes the polynomial seem irreducible but this way of thinking may lead to mistakes, $x(x-2)+a$ seems irreducible (for $a\neq 0$) but $a=1$ shows it is not.

Comment: Replacing $x_{3}$ by $-x_{1}-x_{2}$ !

Comment: can you explain what did you led to say it: "Using $x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}\geqslant |2x_{1}x_{2}|$ you see that this can only hold if $|x_{1}|=|x_{2}|=1$."

Comment: $1=x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{1}x_{2} \geqslant |2x_{1}x_{2}|+x_{1}x_{2} \geqslant |x_{1}x_{2}|$ so $|x_{1}|=|x_{2}|=1$ since $x_{1},x_{2}$ can't be $0$.